# Laravel Validation Date does not match the format

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, date-format, laravel-5.1, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate a date in Laravel. I am using `datepicker` in the frontend where the JavaScript sends the date to the server Laravel in this format `dd-MMMM-yy`:

```
$scope.formData.dob = $filter('date')(scope.formData.dob, 'dd-MMMM-yy');
```

My laravel has a validation like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($postData, [
             'dob'       => 'date_format:"dd-MMMM-yy"',
         ]);
```

However the validator keeps saying that the date does not match the format `dd-MMMM-yy`:

> The dob does not match the format dd-MMMM-yy.

I thought maybe it has to do with the format type so I tried changing it to different formats like d/m/y, dd-mm-yyyy, etc.. in both JavaScript date and Laravel date validation but everything keeps saying the same error that the date doesn't match. The output seems fine though and it is in the format I have mentioned in validation. I dont understand why Laravel validation fails.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong format. You need to use standard PHP formats, which is what `Carbon` and, in turn, Laravel's validation uses. You can find them in the PHP Docs for [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

What you actually want is `d-F-y`, I believe.

Comment: hm. that makes sense. I will give that a try now and post back

Comment: Perfect. That works! Thank you so much. I was stuck on that the whole evening!

Comment: @Neel No problem. Be sure to read through the docs for `date()` that I linked. PHP's date formats are drastically different than what you would be accustomed to from Javascript and many other languages/libraries.